# How do I access my form data when sending it from an AJAX request when using Formidable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, formidable

I'm trying to get my AJAX request to send a form over to my server so I can parse through it using formidable, but when I try to access the actual form I'm getting an empty formdata object.

I've tried hacking different parts of the form together in one formdata object then sending it through, but I'm still getting an empty form.

Server side js

```
app.post('/save_file', function(req,res){  //server side js

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
console.log("Form");
console.log(form);

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, file_parse)
{
    console.log("Started form parsing");
    console.log(fields);
});
```

});

Client Side JS

```
function save_file() 
{
         $.ajax({
             url: "save_file",                
             type: "post",                            
             data: $('upload_form'),     
             success: function(response) 
             {
                 console.log("It worked");              
             }            
         }); 
 }
```

If anyone could explain why I'm not getting any data from my forms, I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: `data: $('upload_form'),`

Comment: @AlonEitan what did you mean by your previous statement?  upload_form is the name of my form